# Large dropdown div will appear on click of button with class navbar-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I want have something like navbar-toggle. When user click on it the large div in width and height open open up just like when clicking on navbar-header containg button with class "navbar-toggle"

Any idea of how can I do this using bootstrap?

I have something like this for simple drop down menu but it's a navbar I hope you understand me.

```
   <div class="bs-example">
<nav id="myNavbar" style="width:95%;" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Category</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: create an example on jsfiddle please..

Answer (score 1):

You can create it by `jQuery` click function. it's very simple.

```
 jQuery(".classNameWhichWillShow").hide();
    jQuery(".class_name_where_click").click(function(){
          jQuery(".classNameWhichWillShow").slideToggle(100);
       });
```